# Visual Studio 2022 - Where is the RouterConfig.cs and Global.asax in MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2022

I am new to Visual Studio and ASP.NET and I am watching a tutorial by Mosh Hamedani on MVC development.  The tutorial is a couple of years old, but when he creates a new ASP.NET MVC project, it has an App_Start folder with a RouterConfig.cs file, and also a Global.asax file.  Both of these things are missing from a project created in Visual Studio 2022, and thus the tutorials are failing because of lack of proper routing.

Is there a way to get Visual Studio to create this older project setup, or to get access to these files and folders, or will this tutorial be totally useless to me?

Comment: Those files are from old iteration of ASP.NET. I would recommend you to find a newer tutorial - for ASP.NET Core. A lot of things has changed since that moment.

Comment: Maybe you're trying to create a `.NET Core` version while your tutorial uses the `.NET Framework` version. I never tried VS 2022, but I think it's still possible to create old .NET Framework web applications. There may be a search box around while creating the project, Just try to search for "web application" and see if there are two versions. If so, choose .NET Framework.

Comment: @AlielsonPiffer Bingo!  With the standard Visual Studio 2022 install, you only get .NET Core for web development.  I had to install other packages in Visual Studio to even get access to a .NET Framework version for web development.  And it contained the necessary files.  Sadly, I do not want to learn on Framework, I want to learn on Core, but for now this will have to do until I can figure out how to add Routing with .NET Core.

Comment: @saxofon If you don't want to learn .NET Core, it can't be enough. .NET Core has a completely different system, you learn outdated things that you won't use.

Answer (score 1):

you are following a .net framework tutorial and you are working on a .net core project, create the project again and choose:

Web Application ASP.NET (.NET Framework)

then you can choose MVC

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose: Web Application ASP.NET (.NET Framework)
And then, MVC or API web

Answer (score 0):

you can just add new folder in your project for routeconfig.cs for the routing purpose
and for global.asax can be added manually
.net core stillhave some basic framework function and for further info you can go to microsoft official site .net docs.